# Can someome explain me the below awk substring command val=$( echo $text $len|awk '{print substr($0,0,$2)}')

Tags: awk

command:  `val=$( echo $text $len|awk '{print substr($0,0,$2)}')`

The above command works fine. I just want to understand the values taken by $0 and $2. I understand $0 takes the value of $text and $2 takes the value of $len. But what about $1 ???

Comment: See the manpage for `awk`.

Answer (score 4):

- `$0` is whole line, (both `$text` and `$len` )
- `$2` is second arguement (`$len`)

It look like `substr($0,0,$2`) should be `substr($1,0,$2)`, however, if `$len` is small enough (smaller than actual length of `$text`), it shouldn't matter.

On a side, note:

```
val=${text:0:$len}
```

should do the trick in most shell.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. I've tried the other command val=${text:0:$len} already which is quiet easy but it doesn't seem to work for me, so i went for awk

Comment: @DhivyaBalaPalanisamy what shell are you using?  It should work in most modern bourne-like shells, including `bash`, `zsh`, and `zsh`, but not `dash`.  It also doesn't work in `csh`-like shells.

Comment: substr starts in 1, this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `awk` starts counting from `1`, not from `0`. The first block is `$1`, the second `$2`, and so on. `$0` is actually the whole line you pipe into `awk`, all blocks together.

## More in detail:

OK, first I assume you run the thing within a shell like `bash`, and the part `val=$( echo $text $len|awk '<awk-script>')` is interpreted by the shell, and only `{print substr($0,0,$2)}` is the actual `awk`-script.

Now, let's have a look at the manpage of awk (`man awk`):

> The awk utility shall denote the first field in a record `$1`, the second `$2`, and so on. The symbol `$0` shall refer to the entire record[...].

and

> `substr(s, m[, n ])`
>           Return the at most `n`-character substring of `s` that begins at position `m`, numbering from `1`. If `n` is omitted, or if `n` specifies more characters than are left in the string, the length of the substring shall be limited by the length of the string `s`.

So, first note that the numbering of the length arguments of `substr` also starts with `1`, so better use `substr($0,1,$2)` instead of `substr($0,0,$2)`.

So, the first block (`$text` in your example) you pipe into `awk` is a string, and the second "block" (`$len` in your example) needs to be an integer number describing how many characters of *all the blocks together*, starting from the first character, you want to get back.

OK, and now try:

```
echo ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 2 | awk '{print substr($0,1)}'
```

gives

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 2
```

i.e. the *full* input.

```
echo ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 2 | awk '{print substr($1,1)}'
```

gives

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

i.e. the complete first block.

And so

```
echo ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "${len}" | awk '{print substr($0,1,$2)}'
```

would give the first `$len` characters of `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "$len"`, i.e. of the text by itself *and* the `$len`.

If you only want to have the first `$len` characters of `$text`, try

```
val=$( echo $text $len|awk '{print substr($1,1,$2)}')
```

i.e. changing the `$0` to `$1` within the awk-script.

Also consider to "escape" the shell arguments with double quotes, i.e.

```
val="$(echo "$text" "$len" | awk '{print substr($1,1,$2)}')"
```

would often be the thing one wants (at least the quotes around the whole `$([...])`-thing and around `$text`, for `$len` you can skip it).

Comment: Thanks!. Good explanation. One small doubt, the command                   print substr($1,0,$2) works even if i pass the middle parameter with 0. so even if we pass zero the command starts counting from 1 right...

Comment: @DhivyaBalaPalanisamy: Yes, looks like that, but it's not documented, so I would not rely on that.